# How to find out where a popover is called

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have two viewcontrollers which both call a popover, how to i detect which view has called the popover.

thanks

i call the popover by the following method

```
    EditPupilSelectController = [[EditPupilSelect alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditPupilSelect" bundle:nil];
    [EditPupilSelectController setDelegate:(id)self];
    EditPupilSelectPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:EditPupilSelectController];

    EditPupilSelectPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(700, 1000);

    if ([EditPupilSelectPopoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [EditPupilSelectPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        CGRect popRect = CGRectMake((0),    (0),    (1),    (1));
        [EditPupilSelectPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: To do what with? You could check the delegate, or set the object to another propert.

Comment: i send different data back to the different view controllers, hence i call delegates dependant on which view called it

Comment: you just set a tag and examine the tag to differentiate